# Latex removes whitespaces

Tags: math-mode, errors

Hello I have a problem with whitespaces. I don't know why but they are removed as you can see in the image. Does anybody know why? thank you!
Here is the log:
    Missing $ inserted.

```
<inserted text> $ l.181 \end{frame} I've inserted a begin-math/end-mathsymbol since I think you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

And here is the code:

```
\section{Autómata determinista finito}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{frame}{First Slide Title}{Optional Subtitle}
  \begin{block}{Definición}
Un ADF o autómata determinista finito es una 5-tupla, M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q0 , F), donde :\newline 
Q es un conjunto finito de estados de M\newline
\Sigma es el alfabeto (finito) de entrada de M \newline
\delta: Q \times \Sigma \rightarrow Q es la función de transición de estados
q0 es el estado inicial de M\newline
F \subseteq Q es el set de estados finales de M\newline
\end{block}
```

[image: screenshot of the proble]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You get *very many* errors with that. Math formulas should be enclosed between `\(...\)`. So, for instance, `es una 5-tupla, \(M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q0 , F)\),`. Reading a basic guide would help, try http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/

Comment: Thank you! Now it works and I understand where the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consult a good basic LaTeX guide, such as Nicola Talbot's [“LaTeX for Complete Novices”](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)

In line math formulas should be enclosed between `\(` and `\)` (or between a pair of `$` characters).

Also a single symbol can be a math formula, if it denotes a mathematical object. So your example should be

```
\begin{block}{Definición}
Un ADF o autómata determinista finito es una \(5\)-tupla, 
\(M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_{0} , F)\), donde: \\
\(Q\) es un conjunto finito de estados de \(M\) \\
\(\Sigma\) es el alfabeto (finito) de entrada de \(M\) \\
\(\delta\colon Q \times \Sigma \rightarrow Q\) es la función de transición de estados \\
\(q_{0}\) es el estado inicial de \(M\) \\
\(F \subseteq Q\) es el set de estados finales de \(M\)
\end{block}
```

However, as you're doing a list, it would be probably better to have

```
\begin{block}{Definición}
Un ADF o autómata determinista finito es una \(5\)-tupla, 
\(M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_{0} , F)\), donde:
\begin{itemize}
\item \(Q\) es un conjunto finito de estados de \(M\)

\item \(\Sigma\) es el alfabeto (finito) de entrada de \(M\)

\item \(\delta\colon Q \times \Sigma \rightarrow Q\) es la función de transición de estados

\item \(q_{0}\) es el estado inicial de \(M\)

\item \(F \subseteq Q\) es el set de estados finales de \(M\)
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
```